# How to have your delimiter double and single, too

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey

In my custom Notepad++ user-defined language (UDL) for AutoHotkey, I am trying to fix an issue where the colours for variables don't display correctly.

In the UDL configurator, I have, under *Operators & Delimiters*, specified `Delimiter 1 Style` for

```
Open: %
Escape:
Close: %
```

But I need to fix it so that if there is a `%` followed by a space that the colouring for `Delimiter 1` is not continued to the next line.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'd ask that on superuser, not here, as it's not really a programming question...

Comment: It is if I am writing a `.udl` file? Right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution:

In the [UDL documentation](http://udl20.weebly.com/delimiters.html) it says you can use a special code within the styler options to indicate `either / or`.

Thus, for your variable delimiter for the `%` sign, you want to do this:

```
open:  %
escape:
close: ((% EOL))
```

This will provide you with proper colouring in both situations.

Here is what it looks like in the UDL file:

```
<Keywords name="Delimiters">00% 01 02((% EOL)) 03&quot; 04 05&quot; 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
```

Here is my new [AutoHotkey syntax file](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/udl_autohotkey.xml) with working `%` variable markers.

Comment: There is somethign wrong with the server or your second link, I get an error: "An error has been encountered in accessing this page."

Comment: Yes - I see that too - it's on the UDL download page at the Notepad++ wiki - I'm working on getting it fixed...

Comment: Okay, the link has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some months ago. Well, I was able to fix it by downloading a different syntax highlighting file.

Mine is probably not up-to-date any more, but it works pretty good and the most important things are highlighted so check it out: [...\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\Autohotkey.xml](http://pastebin.com/v7grThDf).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<NotepadPlus>
    <AutoComplete language="AutoHotkey">
        <Environment ignoreCase="yes" startFunc="(" stopFunc=")" paramSeparator="," terminal="" additionalWordChar="#{@"/>
        <KeyWord name="Abort"/>
        <KeyWord name="AboveNormal"/>
.
.
.
```

Maybe you need it as well, but I'm not sure: [...\Notepad++\ahk_userDefineLang.xml](http://pastebin.com/sPy8Q2Np)

However, if you find a more updated file, tell me. :)

Comment: Does it work correctly with the % signs?  It should colour `%var%` one way, and `msgbox % var` another way without continuing the `%` colouring until it finds `%` again...  That is the whole point of my question, actually.  So, you can confirm this one works?

Comment: No, this file you link to does not colour both methods.

Comment: I found the solution - check out my answer.